# SQL raw to CodeIgniter MySQL ActiveRecord

Tags: codeigniter

Please help me convert this SQL to CodeIgniter ActiveRecord without using the following:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM inbox ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS query GROUP BY id');
```

Answer (score 0):

CI Active Record does not support subqueries natively. But you can include a [subquery library like this one](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Subqueries) and use it. **I've not used this library before, so this is not tested. But should be enough to get you started.**

```
$this->db->select()->from('query')->group_by('id');
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('select');
$sub->select()->from('index')->order_by('created_at', 'DESC');
$this->subquery->end_subquery('query');
```

Comment: If the question asker is using CodeIgniter 2.1 then this library is not going to work.  The library utilizes the `_compile_select()` and `get_compiled_select()` methods, both of which are unavailable in CI 2.1.  `compile_select()` is protected and `get_compiled_select()` didn't make it into 2.1.

Comment: @birderic - Hmm, I was unaware of this. Then the solution may be in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047554/844726

Comment: I may be wrong, but I tried unsuccessfully to compile the inner query using methods similar to the ones described here: http://heybigname.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/.  As far as I can tell there is currently no way to compile a query without actually running it.