# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object result_array() when I use SQL subquery

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using WAMP server 2.4.
I am trying to get count of distinct months in database but getting this error "Call to a member function row() on a non-object result_array()". This is my code for my model class

```
public function get_current_month()
{

    $this->db->select('(COUNT(DISTINCT  Month))' );
    $this->db->from('site_data');
    $this->db->where('year =(');
    $this->db->select('MAX(year )');
    $this->db->from('site_data)');
    $query = $this->db->get();


    return $query->result_array(); //error here

}
```

I believe this has something to do with sub query in code because when I use this

```
public function get_current_month()
{

    $this->db->select('(COUNT(DISTINCT  Month))' );
    $this->db->from('site_data');
    $this->db->where('year =2013');
    //$this->db->select('MAX(year )');
    //$this->db->from('site_data)');
    $query = $this->db->get();


    return $query->result_array();

}
```

it is working just fine.
I am using codeigniter

Does anyone has idea what is going wrong here.

This is the query which I tested in database it is working perfectly

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH))
FROM site_data
WHERE YEAR = ( 
    SELECT MAX(YEAR) 
    FROM site_data
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way with CI. Please take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record) as it might help you on how to include subqueries.

Comment: `$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter.
 If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you either need to hand-craft your subquery into a `->where()` call or employ some kind of third-party library. See [subquery in codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record) which deals with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have only a passing experience of CI but it looks pretty clear that the way you are trying to call a subquery by nesting a db->select etc. isn't quite right.
There may be a way of building up the subquery but...

For simplicity's sake can you try this:

```
public function get_current_month()
{

    $this->db->select('(COUNT(DISTINCT  Month))' );
    $this->db->from('site_data');
    $this->db->where('year =( SELECT MAX(year) FROM site_data)');
    $query = $this->db->get();


    return $query->result_array(); //error here

}
```

If it works, why make it more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. 
I figured it will be easy to add a function that gets the MAX(year) from database and then pass the value to my function.

I solved it like this

```
public function get_current_month($Year)
{
    $MAXYear=$Year;
    $this->db->select('(COUNT(DISTINCT  Month))' );
    $this->db->from('site_data');
    $this->db->where('year',$MAXYear);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

where year is the value I am passing from controller to get_current_month().

It works like charm.

Thanks a lot for all of your suggestions.