# Nested mysql query not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

My **sql nested query**  is something like this:-

```
$this->db->where_in('order.order_id', "SELECT `booking_id` FROM `booking` where `booking_id`=$id");
```

The problem is, the second parameter in **where_in** is considered as a string not as a query; since it comes under quotes, while printing last executed query through the function:

```
print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

so it returns nothing from the database.

How can I tolerate this problem can anybody please help ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record

Comment: already gone through that, but not getting; cant able to pass variable as like in my query

Comment: I'm unsure why you are using "where_in" when a subquery can only return one column, not a range of values. Also your subquery is completely redundant, you are selecting `booking_id` WHERE `booking_id` is provided by you in your $id variable, which will therefore just return the value of $id. What exactly are you trying to achieve with your query?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$this->db->where();`

then pass in the whole ***where clause*** as a **string**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`$this->db->query("Your Query here");`

or you can do something like this:

```
$whereClaus = "Your where clause";

$this->db->where($whereClause);
```

Comment: but there also the second parameter comes under quotes, i need to eliminate that

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
$this->db->where_in('order.order_id', "SELECT `booking_id` FROM `booking` where `booking_id`=$id",FALSE);  // If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.
```

for more info check this url
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html