# Delete with join in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function delete_ScormByIdPlataforma($id_platform)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("delete from scormvars where scoinstanceid in
                (select scoinstanceid from dispatch where id_licencia in 
                (select id_licencia from licencias where id_plataforma = $id_platform))");
        // return true;
    }
```

This is my function in my model, the query is ok, but I don't know how to execute the query.

Comment: This is how you execute a query in codeigniter, if your database is well configured in application/config/database.
here $query is true or false if the query succeeded or failed.

You can write :

`function delete_ScormByIdPlataforma($id_platform)
    {
        return $this->db->query("delete from scormvars where scoinstanceid in
                (select scoinstanceid from dispatch where id_licencia in 
                (select id_licencia from licencias where id_plataforma = $id_platform))");
    }`

Comment: ok, now i am getting a error: Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\WiccoCloud\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1567

Comment: I think you should find what you need here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589378/codeigniter-cannot-delete-rows-from-database-table-using-join-method

Answer (score 0):

You load the model class, then call the function:

```
$this->load->model('my_class');
$this->my_class->delete_ScormByIdPlataforma($id_platform);
```

Replacing `my_class` with the name of the class.