# What is the sub-query to fetch a data through three different tables in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm passing the *User_name* with reference to that I have to fetch the *visit_id* which is in the third table, since my method is little messy can anyone tell how to achieve this using Codeigniter sub-query?

```
  public function fetch_patient_bill($user_name) {

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $query = $this->db->where('user_name', $user_name);
    $result = $query->get();
    foreach ($result->result() as $user) {}
    $user_id = $user->id;

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('patient_registration');
    $query = $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $result = $query->get();
    foreach ($result->result() as $registration) {}
    $registration_id = $registration->id;

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('patient_visit');
    $query = $this->db->where('patient_id', $registration_id);
    $result = $query->get();
    foreach ($result->result() as $visit) {}
    $visit_id = $visit->id;   //i want to fetch this id
    }
```

Comment: Any efforts from your end?

Comment: @MiyaG Im new to codeigniter, wanted to know about *sub-query*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't clearly understand your question, but you can see an example using sub-queries in CI following this link: [How to use subqueries in active record with Codeigniter](http://wsnippets.com/use-subqueries-active-record-codeigniter/)

There is also a similar post here on StackO: [subquery in codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047554/2971854)

Hope this helps