# Codeigniter Subquery

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query can someone help me transfer it to `codeigniter` style in model.

```
SELECT
    a.*, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comment` c 
        WHERE c.comment_article_id = a.`News_News_ID`
    ) AS counta
FROM
    `news_news` a
```

Update:
I try this and it work nicely but im not sure it is good practice

```
     $sql="SELECT a.*,
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment c WHERE c.comment_article_id = a.`News_News_ID` ) as counta
     FROM `news_news` a";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, array('News_Cate_ID' => $cate), $start, $display);
```

Comment: `CI` allow you to write your custom `sql` but it always a good practice to use standard model way like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` instead of `sub query` and according to your query you didn't need `where` condition while using `joins`

```
$this->db->select('a.*,COUNT(c.*) AS counta');
$this->db->from('news_news AS a');
$this->db->join('comment AS c', 'c.comment_article_id = a.News_News_ID');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

For more [information](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: And how to put my variable there. I have category, start, display

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This query will return each article with comment count

```
$this->db->select('a.*,COUNT(c.*) AS count');
$this->db->from('news_news a');
$this->db->join('comment c', 'a.News_News_ID = c.comment_article_id ','LEFT');
$this->db->group_by('a.News_News_ID')
$query = $this->db->get();
```