# How to run subquery in CI

Tags: sql, codeigniter, subquery

Hello everyone I am trying to run a subquery in codeigniter. And I  have done this

```
$this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friend_list WHERE user_id = '$id')');
```

My function looks like this

```
public function get_all_users()
{

    $id=$this->session->userdata['user_id'];
    $this->db->select("id,username");
    $this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT `friend_id` FROM `friend_list` WHERE `user_id` = '$id')');
    $this->db->where('id !=2');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query=$this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       return $query->result();
    }

    return false;
}
```

but it is returning this error

```
    Message: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'.
```

If i put some value in pace of $id then it gives result. How can i solve this. Please help me.

Comment: Escape quotes or use mixed case `$this->db->where("id NOT IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friend_list WHERE user_id = '$id')");`

Comment: Codeigniter has built in where not in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_not_in#CI_DB_query_builder::where_not_in

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks :)

Comment: Np. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to include library for subquery:

```
$this->load->library('subquery');
```

Then put your query like this:

This is how we can write sub query in CI
method 1:

```
$this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT `friend_id` FROM `friend_list` WHERE `user_id` = '$id')', NULL, FALSE);
```

OR You can also write like this:
method 2:

```
$this->db->select('id,username')->from('users');
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('where_in');
$sub->select('friend_id')->from('friend_list');
$sub->where('user_id', $id);
$this->subquery->end_subquery('id', FALSE);
```

you can check this reference:
[subquery in codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: Just want to clarify that if you want to use the second option you need to add this [library](http://labs.nticompassinc.com/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/) to your CI setup. Because CI doesn't have Any `$this->subquery->start_subquery` function as far I know.

Comment: @disha the subQuery is a library which needs to be loaded before using the subquery methods

Comment: @cyberrspiritt: yes. We need to add librabry for subquery. That is:
$this->load->library('subquery');

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape same (single) quotes:

You should write it as:

```
$this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT `friend_id` FROM `friend_list` WHERE `user_id` = \'$id\')');
```

or

```
$this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT `friend_id` FROM `friend_list` WHERE `user_id` = ' . $id . ')');
```

or

```
$this->db->where("id NOT IN (SELECT `friend_id` FROM `friend_list` WHERE `user_id` = '$id')");
```