# how to change the query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to change the following query with the help of query builder codeigniter?

```
$query=$this->db->query("select a.*,b.nama from transaksi a,
                                    anggota b
                                    where a.no_transaksi='$nomor' and a.no_transaksi
                                    not in(select no_transaksi from pengembalian)
                                    and a.nomor_anggota=b.nomor_anggota");
```

Note: just want to know another way

Comment: you should take a look at `sql join`. [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: It's a bad query!

Comment: Read the manual and try something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('a.*, b.nama');
$this->db->from('transaksi a, anggota b');
$this->db->where('a.no_transaksi', $nomor);
$this->db->where('`a.no_transaksi` NOT IN (SELECT `no_transaksi` FROM `pengembalian`)', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->where('a.nomor_anggota = b.nomor_anggota');
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

The `,NULL,FALSE` in the `where()` tells CodeIgniter not to escape the query, which may mess it up.

Source: [subquery in codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record)