# How can I write subqueries in codeigniter on view page?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. Having problem in making queries in it. How can I write following query in view page of codeigniter?

```
select *
  from registration_status
 where registtration_card_id = (select Max(registration_card_id)
                                  from registration_status
                                 where registration_id = 67);
```

`registration_card_id` increments automatically and `registration_id` is fetched from registration table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subquery in codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Answer (score 0):

to that you need to load instance of CI into view .Just follow the step

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->db->query("Your custome query");
```

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no.

**First** of all, you don't write a query inside a view page of CodeIgniter.

You must do it in Model, that's why CI is MVC framework.

**Second**, you can utilised database View. If you are using MySQL, you can create a View like:

```
CREATE VIEW last_card_id AS
select * 
from registration_status
```

**Third**, you can use aggregate function in the first place without using sub-query, so the View will already contain the maximum registration_card_id based on registration_id. So we edit the View above:

```
CREATE VIEW last_card_id AS
selet max(registration_card_id) as 'max_id'
from registration_status
group by registration_id
```

then in your model file you can call the model:

```
public function get_max_card_id($registration_id){
    $this->db->where('registration_id',$registration_id);
    return $this->db->get('last_card_id')->row_array();
}
```

then in your controller:

```
public function max_card(){
    $data['registration'] = $this->registration_model->get_max_card_id($registration_id);
    $this->load->view('view_page',$data);
}
```

in view file:

```
<?php echo $registration['max_id'];?>
```

Comment: Thanks.for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select("*")
    ->from("registration_status")
    ->where("registtration_card_id = (select Max(registration_card_id) from registration_status where registration_id = 67 )",false,false)
            ->get()->result();
```

This is using active records