# How to convert this mysqli_fetch_array code to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I convert this mysqli_fetch_array in php to codeigniter?

```
$kueri7 = "SELECT ceil(count(kelas_id)/(select count(user_id) from tuser where matpel_id = $idmatpel)) as jumlah from tkelas";
$cocok8 = mysqli_query($con, $kueri7);
$cocok_kelas_maksimal = mysqli_fetch_array($cocok8);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html & https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html - check this one

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With codeIgniter, your code would look like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT ceil(count(kelas_id)/(select count(user_id) from tuser where matpel_id = $idmatpel)) as jumlah from tkelas", FALSE);
$cocok_kelas_maksimal = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: And for result object array `$cocok_kelas_maksimal = $query->result();`